# Filtering and Ordering based on multiple request.GET parameters

Tags: python, django, sorting

I'm currently stuck in trying to find a solution to my problem. So I have a URL which is like so:

`https://www.domain.com/forum/topic/`

In my template view, I have a form and an input which is responsible for searching for posts:

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search..." value="{{ request.GET.q }}" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" value="Search">
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

In my **Views.py** the search acts as follows:

```
def discussion(request, discussion):
    topics_list = Topic.objects.all().filter(discussion__url=discussion)
    discussion = Discussion.objects.get(url=discussion)

    search_query = request.GET.get('q')

    if search_query:
        topics_list = topics_list.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=search_query) |
            Q(user__username__icontains=search_query)
            )

    paginator = Paginator(topics_list, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        topics = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        topics = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        topics = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    context = {'topics': topics, 'discussion': discussion,}
    return render(request, 'forum/forum_show_posts.html', context)
```

Now when I run the search It works fine, It actually filters the objects based on my query, thus making the url appear as:

`https://www.domain.com/forum/topic/?q=test`

Now I want to work on a order by for my objects so I proceeded to modify the discussion view to be:

```
def discussion(request, discussion):
    topics_list = Topic.objects.all().filter(discussion__url=discussion)
    discussion = Discussion.objects.get(url=discussion)

    search_query = request.GET.get('q')
    sort_query = request.GET.get('sort')

    if search_query:
        topics_list = topics_list.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=search_query) |
            Q(user__username__icontains=search_query)
            )

    elif sort_query:
        if sort_query == "newest":
            topics_list = topics_list.order_by('-timestamp')
        if sort_query == "oldest":
            topics_list = topics_list.order_by('timestamp')
        if sort_query == "name":
            topics_list = topics_list.order_by('title')

        # sort_query = sort_query.title()

    paginator = Paginator(topics_list, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        topics = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        topics = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        topics = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    context = {'topics': topics, 'discussion': discussion, 'sort_value':sort_query,}
    return render(request, 'forum/forum_show_posts.html', context)
```

and my template to have the corresponding links for each method of ordering:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#">Sort...</a>
        <form method="GET" action="">
            <div class="input-group">
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="submit" name="sort" value="newest">Newest</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="submit" name="sort" value="oldest">Oldest</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="submit" name="sort" value="views">Views</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="submit" name="sort" value="comments">Comments</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="submit" name="sort" value="replies">Replies</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="submit" name="sort" value="name">Name</button>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

Now when I actually go ahead and choose to order by Newest or Oldest, it sorts them, making the url appear as:

`https://www.domain.com/forum/topic/?sort=newest`

My problem is that let's say I wanted to search for 'test' making the URL

`https://www.domain.com/forum/topic/?q=test`

but when I want to sort with the search already, that gets overwritten and instead it just shows all posts, with what I chose to sort it with. How do I get it to sort even with the search already there, and if there is no search still sort it.

From `https://www.domain.com/forum/topic/?q=test` to `https://www.domain.com/forum/topic/?q=test&sort=newest` so It shows the newest of the list of posts with the query 'test'.

Comment: What about storing the `q` parameter in a hidden input of the sort form?

Comment: @JordanJambazov can you elaborate more?

Comment: Part of the problem is that when you submit the sorting, the `q` parameter disappears. The reason is that the sort form has `action=""`. If you store query in a hidden input of the sort form, e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="q" value="{{ request.GET.q }}">`, you will be preserving the query during search as well.

Comment: I did that but It hid the search bar and it still didn't preserve the q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of your `GET` params, update your view to be:

```
def discussion(request, discussion): # <<- view name and var name both are same which might cause issues
    search_query = request.GET.get('q', '')
    sort = request.GET.get('sort', '')
    direction = request.GET.get('dir', 'asc')
    if direction not in ['asc', 'desc']:
        direction = 'asc'

    topics_list = Topic.objects.all().filter(discussion__url=discussion)
    discussion = Discussion.objects.get(url=discussion)

    if search_query:
        topics_list = topics_list.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=search_query) |
            Q(user__username__icontains=search_query)
        )

    if sort:
        order_by = '{0}{1}'.format('-' if direction == 'desc' else '', sort)
        topics_list = topics_list.order_by(order_by)

    # rest of code
    # pass search_query, sort and direction in context
    context = {
        'topics': topics,
        'discussion': discussion,
        'sort': sort,
        'direction': direction,
        'search_query': search_query,
    }

    return render(request, 'forum/forum_show_posts.html', context)
```

Now in template keep track of those params in both forms:

Search Form:

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search..." value="{{ search_query }}" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" value="Search">
        </span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="sort" value="{{ sort }}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="direction" value="{{ direction }}" />
</form>
```

Sort Form:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#">Sort...</a>
        <form method="GET" action="">
            <div class="input-group">
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="submit" name="sort" value="newest">Newest</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="submit" name="sort" value="oldest">Oldest</button>
               <button class="dropdown-item" type="submit" name="sort" value="views">Views</button>
               <button class="dropdown-item" type="submit" name="sort" value="comments">Comments</button>
               <button class="dropdown-item" type="submit" name="sort" value="replies">Replies</button>
               <button class="dropdown-item" type="submit" name="sort" value="name">Name</button>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="search_query" value="{{ search_query }}" />
            <input type="hidden" name="direction" value="{{ direction }}" />

        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to not be ordering the posts regardless of changing from asc or desc, it does however search for posts with the specified text, but it still shows my old queries.

Comment: Thanks! I used some of the code you gave me specially the preserving method for the GET parameters and managed to solve the problem.